# WLI transform xQuery null node

Tags: java, soa, transformation, soapui, wli

**I'm using a WLI SOA Application with Hibernate.**

I have the following class:

```
class PersonDB implements Serializable {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Date dob;
/** getters and setters **/
}
```

In the ModelPerson JPD, I have the following transform:

```
PersonDB personDB;
ModelDocument modelXML;
void transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel throws Exception {
    this.personDB = transformTransactioModel.transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel(this.modelXML);
}
```

In the Transform Abstract Class I have the following tranformation:

```
@com.bea.wli.transform.XQueryTransform(transformType = com.bea.wli.transform.XQueryTransform.TransformMethodType.XQUERY_REF, value = "transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel.xq", schemaValidate = @com.bea.wli.transform.XQueryTransform.SchemaValidate(returnValue = false, parameters = false))
public abstract PersonDB transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel(ModelDocument object);
```

And the xQuery transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel.xq is:

```
declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/Dominio/src/com/process/transformations/transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel/";
declare namespace ns-1 = "person.model.tempuri.com";

declare function xf:transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel($object as element(ns-1:Model)) as element() {
    for $o in $object return (
        <PersonDB>
        {
        for $code in $o/code
        return
            <id?>{ data($code) }</id>
        }
        {
        for $nameOfPerson in $o/nameOfPerson
        return 
            <name?>{ data($nameOfPerson)}</name>
        }
        {
        for $date in $o/date
        return
            <dob?>{ data($date) }</dob>
        }
    </PersonDB>
    )
};

declare variable $object as element(ns-1:Model) external;
xf:transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel($object)
```

Later, when I test an operation through SoapUI, I try with the following request in the first time:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:pers="person.model.tempuri.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <open:find>
     <pers:Model>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <code>100</code>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <nameOfPerson>John</nameOfPerson>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <date>1985-11-23T12:44:07</date>
     </pers:Model>
   </open:find>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This response is ok.

At the second time, I test the following request to return all persons:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:pers="person.model.tempuri.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <open:find>
      <pers:Model>
      </pers:Model>
     </open:find>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This response logs the following error in SoapUI response:

> fc:JWSError
>            Unhandled process exception
>            
>               com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.UnhandledProcessException:
>   Unhandled process exception [ServiceException]    at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.JpdContainer.preInvoke(JpdContainer.java:1043)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.container.Invocable.invoke(Invocable.java:248)
>     at com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.JpdContainer.invoke(JpdContainer.java:814)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.bean.BaseContainerBean.invokeBase(BaseContainerBean.java:224)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.bean.SLSBContainerBean.invoke(SLSBContainerBean.java:136)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlwgen.StatelessContainer_2hozgx_ELOImpl.invoke(StatelessContainer_2hozgx_ELOImpl.java:137)
>     at com.bea.wlwgen.SLSBContAdpt.invokeOnBean(SLSBContAdpt.java:29)   at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.bean.BaseDispatcherBean.runAsInvoke(BaseDispatcherBean.java:185)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.bean.BaseDispatcherBean.invoke(BaseDispatcherBean.java:54)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.bean.SyncDispatcherBean.invoke(SyncDispatcherBean.java:168)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.bean.SyncDispatcher_k1mrl8_EOImpl.invoke(SyncDispatcher_k1mrl8_EOImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.dispatcher.Dispatcher.remoteDispatch(Dispatcher.java:165)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.dispatcher.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.dispatcher.HttpServerHelper.executePostRequest(HttpServerHelper.java:711)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.dispatcher.HttpServer.doPost(HttpServer.java:33)
>     at com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.JpdServlet.doPost(JpdServlet.java:253)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3231)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2002)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1908)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1362)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181) Caused by:
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.UnhandledProcessException: Unhandled process
>   exception     at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.Activity.processException(Activity.java:380)
>     at com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.OnException.rethrow(OnException.java:101)
>     at com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.OnException.execute(OnException.java:198)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.SyncReceive.messageDelivery(SyncReceive.java:63)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.ProcessState.processMessage(ProcessState.java:217)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.ProcessState.dispatchRequest(ProcessState.java:241)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.JpdContainer.dispatchProcessRequest(JpdContainer.java:1077)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.JpdContainer.preInvoke(JpdContainer.java:1041)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: com.bea.transform.TransformException:
>   Unexpected error in transformation - please look at the log for
>   details.  at
>   com.bea.wli.transform.TransformExecutor.executeXQ2004(TransformExecutor.java:245)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.transform.TransformExecutor.execute(TransformExecutor.java:94)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.transform.runtime.DtfDispMethod.invoke(DtfDispMethod.java:393)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.container.Invocable.invoke(Invocable.java:503)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.knex.runtime.core.container.Invocable.invoke(Invocable.java:476)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.transform.runtime.DtfHandler.invoke(DtfHandler.java:112)
>     at
>   com.process.transformations.TransaformTransactionModelImpl.transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel(TransaformTransactionModelImpl.java:436)
>     at
>   com.process.ModeloPerson.transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel(ModeloPerson.java:163)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)     at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.Perform.invoke(Perform.java:39)   at
>   com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.Perform.execute(Perform.java:50)  ... 34 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.bea.wli.xquery.marshall.xq2004.ClassUnmarshaller.isFullNode(ClassUnmarshaller.java:225)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.xquery.marshall.xq2004.ClassUnmarshaller.unmarshall(ClassUnmarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.xquery.marshall.xq2004.PlanUnmarshaller.unmarshall(PlanUnmarshaller.java:13)
>     at
>   com.bea.wli.transform.TransformExecutor.executeXQ2004(TransformExecutor.java:231)
>     ... 47 more

**I think that the problem is when I send a empty $object in xQuery but I don't know how to validate this parameter if is null.**

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but you could try changing your types to indicate the element is optional.  e.g.

```
declare function xf:transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel($object as element(ns-1:Model)?) as element()? {
  ....
};

declare variable $object as element(ns-1:Model)? external;
xf:transformModelXMLToPersonDBModel($object)
```

Notice I added the optional indicator '?' after the item types.